# i am create my new project, i can not understand what the problem and hoe i can resolve it

Tags: reactjs

Creating a new React app in D:\reactcls\mernpro.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
at spawn (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:390:19
at new Promise ()
at install (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:341:10)
at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:468:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting mernpro/ from D:\reactcls
Done.

Comment: try clear your cache and make project again npm cache clean --force than npx clear-npx-cache

Comment: not working yet